# Ordena artigos através de link

Tags: html, wordpress, link, classificação

O wordpress possui um sistema onde vocês ordena quantos arquivos devem aparece na home page, Categorias etc.

Seria possível ordena a quantidade de arquivos através do link do navegador?

Aqui temos uma parte de um link que mostra artigos em ordem alfabetica

```
                ?orderby=title&order=asc
```

Existe algum codigo que se adicionar no codigo acima mostraria a quantidade de artigos que eu queira?.

Exemplo:  ?orderby=title&order=asc 20 artigos

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você possa fazer isso, posts_per_page (n = número de registros), e offset (n = quantos registros vc irá pular):

`?orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=n&offset=n`

Comment: Não funcionou, mas valeu por responder

Comment: Isso é para posts, para arquivos, vai depender do módulo que você está usando.